# Why are bitwise boolean and shift operations called logical operations in CPU architecture?

Tags: cpu-architecture, bitwise-operators, logical-operators, boolean-logic, riscv

This image is from the "Computer Organization and Design" book:

[image: table of logical operations, their C and Java operators, and RISC-V instructions]

As you can see, the left-hand column is labeled as "logical operations", but the operations shown are all bitwise. Conventionally, `&&` and `||` are known as logical operators while `&` and `|` are known as bitwise operators.

They are introducing the table with the following sentences:

> It follows that operations were added to
> programming languages and instruction set architectures to simplify, among other
> things, the packing and unpacking of bits into words. These instructions are called
> logical operations. Figure 2.8 shows logical operations in C, Java, and RISC-V.

Why do you think they write logical operators for `&` and `|`?

Comment: "Operations", not "operators". And technically they *are* logical operations, applied bit-by-bit, but logical operations nonetheless. Then again, I wouldn't include shifts with the logical operations.

Comment: This is just a general wording, which does not necessarily align with specific standard terminology.

Comment: maybe they use "logical operations" to differentiate from "mathematical operations" (I don't know, better ask the author[s])

Comment: @user16320675: Yeah, I think that and "boolean logic" are the source of this terminology.  It's not "arithmetic" working with numbers, it's working with bits.

Comment: Often, "logical" is used an the counterpart to "arithmetical", representing unsigned and signed operations, respectively. For example, the RISC-V instructions `srl` and `sra` stands for *shift right logically* and *arithmetically*, respectively. However, the "Logical" in the heading doesn't follow this pattern, I guess this is a mistake -- you can just read it as "Operations".

Comment: I think your distinction between "logical" and "bitwise" operations stems from C's design choice of using integers of zero and nonzero values in an integer (of say 16 bits) for Boolean values.  This then necessitates that "logical and" cannot be the same operation as "bitwise and", so they had to come up with different names and syntax for them.  Prior to that, I assume that "and" as a computer instruction would have always meant bitwise, i.e. the logical AND operation applied to every bit, and if you only need one Boolean value then you only use one bit.

Comment: Other languages made different choices. E.g. in Forth, FALSE is 0 and TRUE is -1, i.e. 0xffff, so that bitwise AND and logical AND are in fact the very same operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In computer-architecture terminology, operations on numbers are "arithmetic" (e.g. add/sub/mul/div).

Operations on bits are often called "logical" or "logic instructions" **as in "boolean logic"**.  (Arithmetic right shift, shifting in copies of the sign bit, is usually grouped with other shifts as a logic aka bitwise operation.)

For example, in the Wikipedia [ALU (Arithmetic logic unit)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_logic_unit) article, the editor who wrote it says the opcode "*specifies the desired arithmetic or logic operation to be performed by the ALU*".

Agner Fog's [instruction tables](https://agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf) of his per-instruction performance-testing results categorizes integer instructions into *Move* / *Arithmetic* / *Logic* (bitwise, shifts, bit-test, `setcc`) / *Control transfer* / *String* (yes, x86 is funky like that) / *Other* (like `leave` and `cpuid`).  And similarly, FP arithmetic vs. logic (yes, SIMD instruction sets provide bitwise boolean instructions for FP/SIMD registers).

CPUs don't have "logical" operations in the sense of C and Java's `&&` or `||` (not even for integer inputs without considering the short-circuit eval), so **in the context of computer architecture, "logical" has a different meaning than in software where they needed to distinguish bitwise from the more complicated operation of logical operators.**
The computer architecture usage is older, I assume.

---

Your book isn't saying that `&` in C or Java is a "logical operat**or**", but it is saying that an `and` instruction performs a "logical operat**ion**" in the computer-architecture sense of the word.  The corresponding C and Java operator is the bitwise `&` operator.

Machine code doesn't have operators, just instructions.  (Assembly language has operations on assemble-time constants, like `andi x1, x2, (1<<4)-1` as an alternate way of writing `andi x1, x2, 0x0f`. But this is purely a feature of an assembler, and not something an ISA reference manual will discuss.)

---

Usage citations from random tutorials or guides that came up when I googled `computer architecture logical operations`

- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-are-logic-micro-operations-in-computer-architecture "*Logic operations are binary micro-operations implemented on the bits saved in the registers. These operations treated each bit independently and create them as binary variables.*"
- https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/computer-science/logical-operation quotes some books, like *Harris & Harris: Digital Design and Computer Architecture, 2016* - "*ARM logical operations include AND, ORR (OR), EOR (XOR), and BIC (bit clear)*".  The same authors wrote the same thing about MIPS bitwise instructions.
- https://www.techtarget.com/whatis/definition/arithmetic-logic-unit-ALU